# Symmetrical 0,1 matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to create all 0,1 NxN matrices with zero diagonal. Matrices must be symmetrical. In every column and row must be at least one 1. Any ideas that can help?

Comment: `triu(ones(5),1)+triu(ones(5),1)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**getting all possible matrices of that form**

The idea is that each matrix of this type with size NxN  is defined by its upper diagonal values. Therefore, iterating over all the possible patterns for the upper diagonal part, and coping these values to the lower diagonal will do the trick.
Code example:

```
%defines N
N = 3;

%calculates degree of freedom
nValuesToRand = ((N*N) - N)/2;

%generate all possible binary patterns of size nValuesToRand 
B = dec2bin(0:2^nValuesToRand - 1);

%masks of lower and upper diagonal - will be used later on
upperTriagonalMask = logical(triu(ones(N,N)) - eye(N));
lowerTriagonalMask = logical(tril(ones(N,N)) - eye(N));

%generates a new cell to hold the matrices
allMatrices = cell(size(B,1),1);

%iterates over all possible patterns
for i=1:size(B,1)

    %generates a new matrix
    mat = zeros(N,N);

    %initializes its upper diagonal according to the binary pattern
    mat(upperTriagonalMask) = logical(B(i,:)- 48);

    %copies the upper triagonal to the lower triagonal (for symmetricality)
    upperTriagonalTransposed = triu(mat)';
    mat(lowerTriagonalMask) = upperTriagonalTransposed(lowerTriagonalMask);

    %ignores illegal Matrices 
    if sum(sum(mat,2)==0)>0
        continue;
    end

    %saves mat in the cell
    allMatrices{i} = mat;

end

%cleanes cell
allMatrices = allMatrices(~cellfun(@isempty, allMatrices));
```

**Random matrix generation**

generating all possible matrices for large N values is computationally hard.
If you want to generate a matrix randomly, you can try the following approach:

```
%Dimension size
N = 6;

%Probability for appearance of 0
P = 0.5;

%A mask of the lower diagonal, to be used later on
lowerTriagonalMask = logical(tril(ones(N,N)));

%initializes the matrix
mat = zeros(N,N);

%runs the loop as long as the matrix is not valid
while (sum(mat,2)==0)>0

    %defines a random binary matrix
    mat = rand(N,N) > P;

    %zero out the diagonal values
    mat(logical(eye(N))) = 0;

    %copies the upper triagonal to the lower triagonal (for symmetricality)
    upperTriagonalTransposed = triu(mat)';
    mat(lowerTriagonalMask) = upperTriagonalTransposed(lowerTriagonalMask);

end

%testing
issymmetric(double(mat))
mat
```

result:

```
ans = 

1

mat =

 0     1     1     1     0     0
 1     0     1     1     1     1
 1     1     0     0     0     1
 1     1     0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0     0     1
 0     1     1     1     1     0
```

Comment: Thanks for respond @drorco . Still don't know how to generate all matrices that meet the conditions.

Comment: @Kajko **all**? Do you realize how many there are? It is uncountable for large values of `N`.

Comment: @rayryeng of course there is plenty of them, therefore the maximum of N that I need is 6. This should be accetable value.

Comment: @Kajko Why don't you use this code as a base and carry on the rest yourself?  You haven't shown any effort so the fact that this code is available to you is a blessing.

Comment: @ rayryeng Don't get me wrong. This is just a part of whole thing. I wouldn't ask for help if I haven't tried enough. Since I am matlab begginer it is pretty hard to understand it all. And I really appreciate help.

Comment: @Kajko I understand. It wasn't obvious that you tried anything so apologies for the comment.

Comment: @Kajko, I updated my answer, I hope that you'll find it helpfull